# A machine learning model that classifies dogs

Tags: python, machine-learning, deployment, streamlit

#question
Hello.
There was a problem deploying to streamlit. I did the same as in the video but it says something wrong.

I wrote the code correctly, I used `venv`. but for some reason it is not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpNIU.jpg)

[text](https://github.com/sitbayevalibek/dog-classification/issues/1)

My GitHub profile shows the problem in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the code in kaggle or google colab notebooks. Then run this `!nvidia-smi`

find you have cuda, it shows cuda version. and use `device = torch.device("cpu")`.

When you training the model use `model_0 = modelname().to("cuda")`

Comment: My torch versions seem to be incompatible. But I still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because the server of Streamlit does not have GPU instances so try to load your model in CPU rather than GPU(CUDA)

use this:

```
device = torch.device("cpu")
```

Comment: Still got the same error.